# How to unmerge cells and fill with duplicate values using Java apache POI lib?

Tags: java, java-8, apache-poi

[image]

Giving column name as input (eg. Class).

Answer (score 1):

I created a Excel that looks exactly like yours, except the formating but content is identically.
Apache POI makes this pretty easy and straight forward(as i think)

```
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++)
            {
                CellRangeAddress range = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
                //Use what you need if you just got rows merged endingColumn == startingColumn same goes for rows and merged Columns
                int startingColumn = range.getFirstColumn();
                int endingColumn = range.getLastColumn();
                int startingRow = range.getFirstRow();
                int endingRow = range.getLastRow();
                //This will hold the value e.g. 'Class 1'
                String value = sheet.getRow(startingRow).getCell(startingColumn).getStringCellValue();
                //Necessary otherwise next for loop will just not overwrite your merged Regions
                sheet.removeMergedRegion(i);
                for (int rowIdx = startingRow; rowIdx <= endingRow; rowIdx++)
                {
                    //Just delete this For-Loop if you just merge Rows then cellIdx is just the starting/endingColumn
                    for (int cellIdx = startingColumn; cellIdx <= endingColumn; cellIdx++)
                    {
                       sheet.getRow(rowIdx).getCell(cellIdx).setCellValue(value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The only thing cells within a merged region will automaticall be set to centered. So if you don't want this you have the set the cell type as you want it before you write it out

Kind regards